# Why does a chordal graph have induced cycles of length 3?

Tags: graph-theory, chordal-graphs

I understand that that is the definition. I think I am just not strong on the subject. What would happen if an induced cycle had, say, length 4?

Comment: (But also I'm not clear on what your question is. Are you asking why the definition is an interesting one to make?)

Comment: @GerryMyerson It's too late for me to edit my comment, but I meant "induced" cycle, not "closed" cycle. I'm not sure what a "closed" cycle as opposed to an "open" one even is.

Comment: Trees are chordal graphs but do not have induced cycles of length 3 (or of any length). What is true is: if it has any cycle, then it has an induced cycle of length 3. The usual definition of chordal graphs is that they are the graphs such that any cycle of length greater than 3  has a chord (so is not induced). Suppose there is a cycle, take one of minimum length, it is easy to see that by minimality it does not have any chord, hence it is induced, hence it has length 3. I am also not clear on what your question is, but I hope this will help.